# STS - Cannot start a Spring-Starter-Project using gradle after upgrading to buildship-eclipse-gradle-plugin 2.0

Tags: spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

After i updated Buildship Eclipse Gradle plugin to 2.0, i cannot create Starter projects anymore.

[image]

Using STS `3.8.3.RELEASE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in STS 3.8.3 and got fixed in the meantime. Please refer to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues/90 for more details and how to get the fix immediately.